# Nodejs server and android client

Tags: android, node.js

I have a simple nodejs server:

```
"use strict";

var http = require("http");

var server = http.createServer(processRequest).listen(3001, "192.168.1.4");

function processRequest(request, response) {

    response.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "text/html"
    });

    response.write("Simple HTML Page");

    response.end();

}


// Buradan sonrası yeni
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    sendMessage(socket);
    console.log("User Connected");

    socket.on("disconnect", function () {

        console.log("User Disconnected");
    });
});

function sendMessage(socket) {

    setTimeout(function () {
        socket.emit("test");

        sendMessage(socket);
    }, 5000);
}
```

I want to get data from mysql server (remote) with nodejs and broadcasting to android phones. When the new data add in db, phones show the new data.
How can i communicate with Android Client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`GCM`](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

The flow will be like this:

```
             JSON Package
node Server --------------> GCM Server ---> Android Device
                                                   |
                               (OS notifies app)   |
                                                   V
                                App Connects to node and fetches the data
```

Comment: why cant i use socket.io on android?

Comment: You can definitely use socket.io, but only thing is device will maintain a persistent socket connection with server which might effect battery life. If you want your device to be notified of the data update immediately, opening a socket is the best solution.

Comment: sending datas can be bigger than 4KB so i must using socket.io after notify the system with gcm. Can you give me any example about socket.io usage on android?